# Procedure for broken links

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, flagging

What is the correct thing to do when one finds a broken link in one of the questions or answers? Until now I have flagged them for the moderator, but sometimes these have been declined as being not being the job of the mod. and sometimes they have been accepted as being helpful.

Is there a consensus as to the correct procedure?

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to replace the broken link (you know what it should be), please edit the post.

If it's broken but you don't know what to replace it with, please add a comment pointing out the problem.  (Feel free to also point it out in chat, particularly if it's an older post where people are less likely to see your comment on their own.)

If it's a link-only answer and the link is dead, please flag.  Link-only answers are pretty iffy to begin with (historically Mi Yodeya tolerated them but they really run against SE guidelines), but if that link is also *broken* then any value the answer still had is now gone and it should be deleted.

Comment: ie. flag if you want deletion/conversion-to-comment, an action only a mod can perform.

Comment: Thanks Monica and AA